# How to get title tag of an external page with http api?

Tags: api, http

What is the best method to retrieve the title tag of an external page using the http api?

The snippet below will get the body but I can't find the right documentation about how to just get the  tag.  :/

```
$url = 'http://wordpres.org';
$response = wp_remote_get( $url );
if( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
   echo 'Something went wrong!';
} else {
print wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
}
```

> **Edit:** This code snippet gets both the screenshot
>   and title of an external page (Thanks again @Bainternet). With a
>   little editing this could be an easy
>   way to display the link post format.

```
<?php 
$content = get_the_content();
$url = strip_tags($content); //assumes only a url is in the_content
$width = '150';
$cleanurl = urlencode(clean_url($url));
$fullurl = 'http://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/' . $cleanurl . '?w=' . $width;

// return title tag of an external page
// http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19424/how-to-get-title-tag-of-an-external-page-with-http-api
function get_page_title($url){
    if( !class_exists( 'WP_Http' ) )
        include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC. '/class-http.php' );
    $request = new WP_Http;
    $result = $request->request( $url );
    if( is_wp_error( $result ) )
        return false;

    if( preg_match("#<title>(.+)<\/title>#iU", $result['body'], $t))  {
        return trim($t[1]);
    } else { 
return false; }
    }
$title = get_page_title($url);      

echo '<div class="grid_4 alpha"><a href="' . $url . '"><img src="' . $fullurl . '" width="' . $width .'px" /></a></div>'; 
echo '<div class="grid_10 omega"><h3>'; if ($title !== false){ echo $title;} echo '</h3><p>' . $content . '</p></div>';
echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a function i have for that:

```
function get_page_title($url){
        if( !class_exists( 'WP_Http' ) )
            include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC. '/class-http.php' );
        $request = new WP_Http;
        $result = $request->request( $url );
        if( is_wp_error( $result ) )
            return false;

        if( preg_match("#<title>(.+)<\/title>#iU", $result['body'], $t))  {
            return trim($t[1]);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
$title = get_page_title('http://www.google.com');
if ($title !== false){ echo $title;}
```

Comment: thank you for the function! It's giving me this error though, any thoughts? `Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in *** on line 26` which is `if( preg_match("#<title>(.+)<\/title>#iU", $result, $t))  {`.

Comment: yeah my bad , change `$result` to `$result['body']` in that line.

Comment: that worked. I combined and posted your snippet with my mshots snippet above. Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't want to `print` the response, you'll want to store it in a variable.  Then you can use a RegEx to find the text inside `<title>` and `</title>`.

```
preg_match( $pattern, wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), $matches );
```

Your `$matches` variable will then be an array.  Just use `$matches[0]` and you'll have the title tag.

This pattern will extract `<title>Your Title</title>` out of the page:

```
$pattern = '/<title>([^>]*)<\/title>/';
```

I leave it up to you to remove the `<title>` and `</title>`.